# How to return object of constructor from inside the constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

How can I return the object from constructor from inside the constructor?

```js
 function consFunc() {
  
    this.flag = 'someFlag';
    this.pol = 'somePole';        

    }

    consFunc.prototype.foo = function(){      
     console.log(this.flag);
    }

    var obj = new consFunc();
    obj.foo();
```

This is how usually I make object from constructor. How can I return object from inside the constructor function so I no need to write  `var obj = new consFunc();` I just simply call `obj.foo();` for my need, is it possible?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What would `obj` be if it isn't `new consFunc();`?

Comment: this is just for example

Comment: That doesn't explain much.

Comment: I am not sure how it should be, maybe I should say consFunc.foo(); i dont know

Comment: What is wrong with using `new consFunc();`?

Comment: for example the jquery, we just pass the selector $('div').hide(); and call the function it works

Comment: @Mohsin have you tried using new consFunc().foo();  ? it returns someFlag

Comment: @Mohsin I think you want a simple object with a function on it without the need to create an instance with `new`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes Henry it's giving an error uncaught type error

Comment: yes Alex it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your constructor in another function and return `new consFunc();` from that function:

```js
function obj() {
  function consFunc() {
    this.flag = 'someFlag';
    this.pol = 'somePole';
  }
  consFunc.prototype.foo = function () {
    console.log(this.flag);
  }      
  return new consFunc();
}
// now use it
obj().foo()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an object with a simple function on it you can simply write

```
var consObj = {
  flag: 'someFlag',
  pol: 'somePole',       
  foo: function() { console.log( this.flag ); }
}

consObj.foo() // 'someFlag'
```

Comment: haven't you noticed he's using prototype to add a method?? Your answer isn't helping much

Comment: @HenryDev I don't think he wants a prototype, check the comment in which I asked what he actually needs

Comment: yes I'm with you, but have you seen that in the very beginning of his code he's using prototype?

Comment: No Alex I was in need of doing it with prototype

Comment: I would advise against the usage of prototypes and constructor functions for situations like this. Please provide more context around your need so we can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

If you need some sort of singleton:

```
var obj = (function (){

    var flag = 'someFlag';
    var pol = 'somePole';   

    function foo(){      
        console.log(flag);
    }

    return {
      foo: foo
    };
})();

obj.foo();
```